# Tool for generating custom configuration sections

Tags: .net, configuration, code-generation

We all live with the .NET configuration file XML format (e.g. Web.config, App.config, etc).

[Creating the code for custom configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) is straight forward but somewhat monotonous. Is there a good tool to build custom configuration sections that generates the classes?

Ideally the tool would also look at sample XML sections built by hand and reverse engineer 
them into classes. Tweaking would need to be involved with the tool because it can't guess all aspects of usage.

I generate enough custom configuration sections for components that this tool would be well used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com)?

[image: Configuration Section Designer in Action]

I have used this and customized it. It comes with full source code.

Comment: Additionally it's based on T4 which is what I started to look into after posting the question. Nice find. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnK: further, it's based on the DSL toolkit. I've customized not only the T4 but also the DSL and the Visual Studio interface code.